# redirecting page to 404

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've found a few pages for redirecting a single page to 404 but it's not working. Here is my simple line

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/showthread.php?p=3164554$
```

It does not work though. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to escape the `\.php`

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration tries to redirect the page "404" to the page "^/showthread.php?p=3164554$" (see the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)).

`RedirectMatch` generates a redirection : you can't redirect with a HTTP 404 code. When redirecting, you may have issues with the query string (I couldn't match the query string), I would use rewrite rules :

You can redirect to a 404.html page with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p=3164554
# the empty question mark discard the query string
RewriteRule  ^/showthread\.php    404.html?    [L,R=301]
```

Or you can stay on the same url but show the 404 page :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p=3164554
RewriteRule  ^/showthread\.php      -          [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to escape your `.` character with `\` like this.Let me know, it works for you or not.

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/showthread\.php?p=3164554$
```

Comment: hmmm still doesn't work. is there anywhere special I need to put the line?